# How to use global_costmap/costmap_updates for updating global costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've already search through the Internet and still get no clue of how to update the global cost map in navigation node, hydro.
I've create a new package and subscribe to global costmap generated from SLAM, but the update is only occurs at the first time of lashing. In rviz everything is fine, the global map is update in realtime. Any answer will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142736/how-to-use--global_costmap/costmap_updates-for-updating-global-costmap/) by [noizpgt](https://answers.ros.org/users/13196/noizpgt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-04-16**:
Good question.. I am interested in having an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to subscribe to both .../costmap and .../costmap_updates.

---

Originally posted by [Siegfried Gevatter](https://answers.ros.org/users/1599/siegfried-gevatter/) with karma: 119 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-05-14**:
This is correct.

**Comment by [zebfour](https://answers.ros.org/users/128438/zebfour/) on 2022-12-21**:
Sorry for necroposting but there doesn't seem to be a tutorial about this... could you tell me more about how to use them jointly?